# Print the class loading order while starting a quarkus service

Tags: java, classloader, quarkus

We seem to have a conflict in loading the ObjectMapper when the Quarkus service starts. In one of the common jars which the service dependeds on, we have set the deserialization property FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES  to false, but at runtime the value is true when the ObjectMapper is getting used. We want to know which dependency may be setting this to true or overriding our configuration at runtime.

Is there a way we can print/log the class loading order from the various dependency jars during service startup?

Comment: You can use the `-verbose:class` JVM flag to get verbose ClassLoading logging information but I am not sure it will help. It would probably be easier to add a breakpoint in `ObjectMapper` and print the stacktrace when the breakpoint is reached.

Comment: Its deployed in a pod on kubernetes, makes it harder to debug that way, so looking at some programmatic way which can put this information to the log file